# Cache Total Entries increase and decrease as a delta shape. Why?

Tags: performance, asp.net, memory, cache, perfmon

My performance counter "cache total entries" "cache total hits" "cache total misses" keeps increasing and decreasing as a delta shape around every 1 hour.The decreasing is much fast than increasing. The "hit ratio" is stable and "total trim" keeps 0. Do you have any idea about what might cause this ? I tried to google, but except definition of these counters, nothing more. I can't correlated this issue with my knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: Could use some clarity on which section you're seeing these in. Is it IIS, ASP, Logical Disk, Memory? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the general behavior sounds normal, since the three entries are inherently related. Total hits plus total misses should equal total entries. For normal usage, the hit ratio is probably going to stay steady, since that is the ratio of total hits versus total entries.

Are you sure you're not just getting spurts of increased usage? Some sort of scheduled task maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Hyppy. I am using the asp.net memory cache counter. The private bytes did increase at the time frame when cache counters (.net) increasing and decreasing more frequently than normal times. But the private bytes increasing did not trigger application pool recycle, so I don't quite understand why the cache will free the entries when private bytes consuming at a high level.